# How to go to the previous page without refreshing/reloading in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

So i'm having a ListView in PageA, when i click on a button it redirects me to the PageB, now i do something on PageB, but when i click on Ok/Submit, i need to pass this data to PageA and also load PageA without refreshing or reloading it which would end up refreshing ListView/PageA
Each Update on PageB is basically some content update for each tile of the ListView on PageA, so basically when i click on the first item and return, it should only update that item

I was able to do it by MessagingCenter to subscribe at PageA, and use a dictionary to send back the data to PageB, but if i use Navigation.PopAsync, then it just refreshes the data on PageA

Any viable solution for this, as this is a common feature any app would have but i'm not able to visualize it for some reason

this is my code
PageB

```
 var data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                data.Add("1", "1");
                data.Add("2","2");
                data.Add("3", "3");
                data.Add("4", "4");
                data.Add("5", "5");
                MessagingCenter.Send(data, "SubmitData");
                Navigation.PopAsync();
```

Code PageA

```
 MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Dictionary<string, string>>(this, "SubmitData", (sender) =>
         {
             try
             {
                 sender.TryGetValue("1", out result[0]);
                 sender.TryGetValue("2", out result[1]);
                 sender.TryGetValue("3", out result[2]);
                 sender.TryGetValue("4", out result[3]);
                 sender.TryGetValue("5", out result[4]);
             }
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: are you doing anything in OnAppearing?  And if PageB is just editing an item from PageA, you should be able to pass the item to PageB and edit it without needing to use MessagingCenter

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the data for PageA listview...

Comment: OnAppearing can fire when you navigate BACK to a page, so you need to check that you're not executing your data load more than once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but when i click on Ok/Submit, i need to pass this data to PageA and also load PageA without refreshing or reloading it which would end up refreshing ListView/PageA Each Update on PageB is basically some content update for each tile of the ListView on PageA, so basically when i click on the first item and return, it should only update that item

According to your description, I guess that you want to select one item from ListView on PageA, then pass selected item to PageB, do some change, and go back to PageA and update that item in ListView, am I right?

If yes, I suggest you can take a look the following code:

PageA:

```
 <StackLayout>
        <ListView
            x:Name="listview1"
            ItemsSource="{Binding list}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding selecteditem}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding username}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding age}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

        <Button
            x:Name="btn1"
            Clicked="btn1_Clicked"
            Text="redirect to another page" />
    </StackLayout>

 public partial class Page8 : ContentPage
{
    public viewmodel3 viewmodel { get; set; }
    public Page8()
    {
        viewmodel = new viewmodel3();

        InitializeComponent();

        this.BindingContext = viewmodel;
    }

    private void btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new Page9(viewmodel.selecteditem));
    }     
}

public class viewmodel3:ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<model3> list { get; set; }
    private model3 _selecteditem;
    public model3 selecteditem
    {
        get { return _selecteditem; }
        set
        {
            _selecteditem = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("selecteditem");

        }
    }

    public viewmodel3()
    {
        list = new ObservableCollection<model3>()
        {
            new model3(){username="cherry",age=29},
            new model3(){username="barry",age=32},
            new model3(){username="wendy",age=27}
        };
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<model3>(this, "Update", (person) =>
        {

            updateitem(person);
        });

    }
    private void updateitem(model3 item)
    {
        var person = list.FirstOrDefault(p => p.username == item.username);
        if (person != null)
        {
            person.age = item.age;
        }
    }      
}
public class model3:ViewModelBase
{
    private string _username;
    public string username
    {
        get { return _username; }
        set
        {
            _username = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("username");
        }
    }
    private int _age;
    public int age
    {
        get { return _age; }
        set
        {
            _age = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("age");
        }
    }
}
```

PageB:

```
 <StackLayout>
        <Entry x:Name="username" />
        <Entry x:Name="age" />

        <Button
            x:Name="btnsub"
            Clicked="btnsub_Clicked"
            Text="submit" />
    </StackLayout>

 public partial class Page9 : ContentPage
{
    public model3 item;
    public Page9(model3 m)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        item = new model3();

        item.username = m.username;
        item.age = m.age;

        username.Text = m.username;
        age.Text = m.age.ToString();
    }

    private void btnsub_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         if(item.username!=username.Text || item.age!=int.Parse(age.Text))
        {
            MessagingCenter.Send(new model3() { username = username.Text, age = int.Parse(age.Text) }, "Update");
        }
        Navigation.PopAsync();

    }
}
```